# Select records with one-to-many relationship where all of the many are in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, one-to-many

I have a table of records with a one to many relationship to another table.  I want to return all records in the first table where ALL entries in the second table are found in a comma separated list.

```
Client   ClientData                   Client    Project
John                                  John      1
Jane                                  Jane      2
Mary                                  Mary      3
Randy                                 John      4
                                      Mary      5
                                      Randy     6
                                      Jane      7
```

So, if my list is (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  Then I want to return Client and ClientData for John and Mary.  Jane has one entry in the list, but not all so I don't want her returned.

Comment: John has only 1,4 and Mary has only 3,5, why they need to be returned as all are not matched

Comment: What form does your list take? Will it be a separate table? In a Client-Project table does Client and Project concatenated together form a unique key?

Comment: The list is currently a comma separated list that I've copied from an excel spreadsheet.  Unless there's an easier way to join to a spreadsheet.  I cannot use the spreadsheet to create a new table in the db to join to.

Comment: Both of John's projects are in the list.  Both of Mary's projects are in the list.  So, they should be returned.  One of Jane's projects is not in the list, so she isn't returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM ClientData c
INNER JOIN ProjectData pd
    ON c.client_name = pd.client_name AND pd.project_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
WHERE c.client_name NOT IN (
    SELECT client_name FROM ProjectData WHERE project_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
)
```

Also, I would hope you are using a unique identifier for your clients instead of just a name.

Comment: Yes, it's using unique identifiers.  That was just to make things a little easier to follow.